# Knightlab TimelineJS Timeline Navigation Height Adjustment

Tags: javascript, timeline.js

I'm trying to adjust the height of the Timeline navigation to a accommodate more markers on the same line, I've managed to modify the css to make it look bigger but the placement of the first 5 markers should be on the same line, I'm aware that there have already been some questions on this but they seems to be for an older version of TimelineJS, the latest seems quite different, I need to know what js config setting I can set to allow for more markers on the same, please see this url of my current setup, any help would be great.

http://diaceutics.com/TimelineJS-master/TimelineJS-master/examples/example_json.html

Comment: You actually have the first five markers on the first row, but they are stacked on top of each other (same "x position"). I guess you want to spread them out on the X axis, to make them all visible on the same row. I haven't tried that unfortunately, but I am interested in how to do that, since I have been thinking about a similar view for projects. (However, the limit of rows are six.)

Comment: +1 tried to change the height as well in a project, but it's somehow structurally screwed up, so that it get's too complex. Would be glad to see a solution to this issue.